# How to write a comment that links to a specific line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to write a comment in `VB.NET` that links to a statement, line or object within the same project but different file? If this option is not available in comments, what do you suggest to make linking possible?

I need this function so that I remember to update a method when I apply changes in another one.

Comment: Do you say about references? in new version of VS like 2013 or so, for each property and methods there will be a reference on the top of the line. ex : '2 references | 0 exceptions'

Comment: I see. I am currently using VS2010 which seems to lack this feature

Answer (score 1):

Write a comment above the function as usual, but at the beginning add `TODO` within a few seconds, this comment will show up in your task list window.

If your task list window isn't visible, click on `View` in the top menu strip, click `Other window` and select `Task list`. All your `TODO` comments will show up here. To go to the code relating to the comment, just double click on the relevant comment.

When you have completed what you want to do, simply delete the comment in your code, and it will be removed from the task list.

Comment: Well, it might relieve some pain but the `TODO` command is actually meant for setting a task as reminder to complete an unfinished code. However, I am currently working on a complete code with interrelated methods that can be updated in the future.

Comment: +1 Because I learned about a new window today.  I've always used those comments as a matter of practice, but I didn't know there was a window to view them all together.

Comment: Glad to have helped a little at least.